# How to make a multi-page application in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to make a simple GUI-App in PyQt. When a button gets clicked, it should take you to the next page. It's like these installations dialoges you know when installing a program.

I tried to open a new window at the exact same position like the MainWindow, but that doesen't feel right.

Soo, here's my code:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "MainWindow"
        # Here are some height & width variables
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.UiComponents()
    def UiComponents(self):
        self.searchButton = QPushButton("", self)
        # alot of UiComponents go here
        self.searchButton.clicked.connect(self.make_handleButton("searchButton"))
    def make_handleButton(self, button):
        def handleButton():
            if button == "searchButton":
                ### here it should go to SearchWindow ###
            #elif button == "importButton":
            #    self.importWindow()
        return handleButton

class SearchWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Search for something"
        # Here are some height & width variables
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.UiComponents()
        self.hide()
    def goToMain(self):
        ### here it should go back to the MainWindow ###
    def UiComponents(self):
        self.backButton = QPushButton("BackButton", self)
        self.backButton.setGeometry(QRect(5, 5, self.backButtonWidth, self.backButtonHeight))
        self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.goToMain)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use a QStackWidget, in the following part there is an example:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class PageWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    gotoSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def goto(self, name):
        self.gotoSignal.emit(name)


class MainWindow(PageWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")

    def initUI(self):
        self.UiComponents()

    def UiComponents(self):
        self.searchButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self)
        self.searchButton.clicked.connect(
            self.make_handleButton("searchButton")
        )

    def make_handleButton(self, button):
        def handleButton():
            if button == "searchButton":
                self.goto("search")
        return handleButton


class SearchWindow(PageWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Search for something")
        self.UiComponents()

    def goToMain(self):
        self.goto("main")

    def UiComponents(self):
        self.backButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("BackButton", self)
        self.backButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 5, 100, 20))
        self.backButton.clicked.connect(self.goToMain)


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.stacked_widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stacked_widget)

        self.m_pages = {}

        self.register(MainWindow(), "main")
        self.register(SearchWindow(), "search")

        self.goto("main")

    def register(self, widget, name):
        self.m_pages[name] = widget
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(widget)
        if isinstance(widget, PageWindow):
            widget.gotoSignal.connect(self.goto)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def goto(self, name):
        if name in self.m_pages:
            widget = self.m_pages[name]
            self.stacked_widget.setCurrentWidget(widget)
            self.setWindowTitle(widget.windowTitle())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you. This was a great template and helped me very much!